# Why does VScode sense this string as undefined?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

Here's a bare-bones example. I have a class whose objects have two properties:

- a reference to a parent object of the same class
- some value (in our case a string but it doesn't matter what type it is)

Here's the code:

```js
class Foo {
  /**
   * @param {Foo?} parent
   * @param {string} value */
  constructor(parent, value) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.value = value;
    if(parent) {
      let value = parent.value; // vscode says value is undefined
      console.log(value); // but when printed it's the expected string
    }
  }
}
```

If I mouse over `value` on the commented lines, the intellisense popup simply displays `let value: undefined`, and gives me the red squiggles if I try to do anything with it.
Seeing as the program behaves as expected, I assume the issue lies in my JSdoc.

Note: the nullability of `parent` is not the issue, as this example bears the same problem:

```js
class Foo {
  /**
   * @param {Foo} parent
   * @param {string} value */
  constructor(parent, value) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.value = value;
    let parentValue = parent.value; // vscode says parentValue is undefined
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I convince intellisense that `value` is definitely a string?

Comment: Why do you assume that `parent.value` is defined or a string? Nothing in this code shows what `parent` is

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - `@param {Foo} parent`?

Comment: That's a comment. Not an interface or anything that affects the JavaScript program itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's JSDoc comment that VSCode does pay attention to, since it has full integration with TS and TS itself respects it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html

Comment: @VLAZ and `Foo` itself has no `value` field

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yet it's far from "nothing" that shows what `parent` is. Which is what your original claim was and I disagreed with.

Comment: @VLAZ `new Foo()` is valid, and so is `new Foo(69,45)` so yes, there's nothing that shows what `parent` is. You can't guess whether `value` is defined at all

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos again `@param {Foo} parent` does. And again, VSCode respects the typings in the JSDoc. See https://tsplay.dev/NVez7w for example of how that works. I disagree with your claim claim that JSDoc is not taken into account by VSCode. Can *you* prove what you are saying? That JSDoc has no effect at all to the inferred types in VSCode?

Comment: @VLAZ and again, this `Foo` has no `value`. If you actually type that code in your browser's console and try `new Foo(0,0)` you'll see that `parentValue` is undefined. Yes, I can prove this: `new Foo(0,0)` and `new Foo()`. I *DID NOT* claim that JSDoc isn't taken into account, that's your interpretation. In this case VS Code is perfectly right - you can't know if `value` is defined or not

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how is the browser console related to the type inferrence in VSCode? Why are you talking about runtime behaviour and a different environment when the question is about a specific code editor and how it determines types before running the application? If you take your proposed `new Foo(0,0)` and use it in the TS playground, you'd get an error before even running the code: https://tsplay.dev/Woz28m because the first parameter is typed as `Foo` and `0` is not a valid `Foo` instance.

Comment: Because running code beats inference and `value` is undefined when you actually execute the question's code. And this is Javascript, not Typescript

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "*I DID NOT claim that JSDoc isn't taken into account,*" you repeatedly said there is nothing that says what `parent` is when this is clearly typed by JSDoc to be a `Foo` instance. You also [characterised the JSDoc as a comment only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77805304/why-does-vscode-sense-this-string-as-undefined?noredirect=1#comment137164309_77805304) when it definitely is taken into account.

Comment: `your proposed` not proposed. Actual. This is a JavaScript, not TypeScript question. And `new Foo(0,0)` runs.

Comment: To clarify: The question is about [tag:jsdoc] in [tag:visual-studio-code] - it is *not* a javascript question (despite the tags).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos [I've shown you JS in the playground.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdI9b.png) Twice now. VSCode uses the same engine to do the type inference. And OP is asking about how VSCode's type inference works. What is your final claim then - is or is not JSDoc relevant to the type inference in VSCode?

Comment: I've shown you actual JS you can run in your browser, that proves that `value` is undefined. Twice. You want to keep arguing about wording instead of substance. OK you win.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos browser !== VSCode. The question is about type inference in VSCode. Please stick to the actual topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should define value in Foo

```js
class Foo {
  value = ''
  /**
   * @param {Foo?} parent
   * @param {string} value */
  constructor(parent, value) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.value = value;
    if(parent) {
      let value = parent.value; // vscode says value is undefined
      console.log(value); // but when printed it's the expected string
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Apparently just `value;` does the trick, because the type is correctly inferred from the constructor's JSdoc. I have no idea what makes this case different in that it needs the explicit declaration, but that's good enough for me. Thank you!

Comment: JSdoc just work in current function(include return value), the definition of parent.value is from Foo

Comment: This isn't a matter of *inference*. In the question `Foo` has no `value` field. The field is created when the constructor is executed. There's no guarantee that the constructor will be called though, `new Foo()` is valid

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `new Foo()` would be invalid in VSCode: https://tsplay.dev/mq0bYN The only way to call the constructor is to provide a structurally equivalent instance. This *is* an issue with inference because without declaring `Foo` would have a `value` field, the type inference would allow `Foo` without one. Even though it can't really be constructed that way - every `Foo` instantiated with two values in the constructor (only valid way to call it in VSCode) will have a string for the `value` field (only valid type that goes in that field via the constructor).

Comment: Making sure the type is properly annotated makes the type inference work as intended - the engine now knows of the `value` field and its type. So the `parent` of type `Foo` is then correctly recognised as existing by VSCode:  https://tsplay.dev/NB1qVw The `parent` field will have a similar problem now - it can only be populated by a `Foo` instance but because it's missing in the type information it will not show.